# TypeError: object is not a function Node js Node Authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, express

This is one of my first stack overflow questions, so I'll try to do my best in asking my question..

I'm following this tutorial exactly ( http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local ) and after the third part ( "**Application Setup** server.js) when I try to run the server I get "TypeError: object is not a function" for the line:

```
require('./app/routes.js')(app, pspt); // load our routes and pass in our app
```

I found other people having similar problems that were caused by naming conflicts with local variables.  I tried renaming passport to pspt but it seems like the error was found at the start of the second parenthesis, before my variables. Should I rename the 'app/routes' folder?

Thanks!

EDIT:  Yeah, the tutorial made it seem like it should work right after the third part.  I moved onto the fourth part and it worked fine.  Thanks again.

Comment: What is the source of `/app/routes.js`?

Comment: the problem is in your routes.js. possibly a syntax error? you should post the routes.js code.

Comment: your routes.js should be a big function that takes 2 params (app, pspt) and inside you define the rest of the callbacks. If your routes.js is just a module, then the error is legit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure your `./app/routes.js` module returns a function. It should be something like:

```
module.exports = function(app, passport) {
    //...
};
```